# Error in Syncing tags in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I wanted to sync tags array using eloquent in laravel.

My Tags Migration with Pivot Table Schema looks like following:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('article_id');
        $table->integer('tag_id');
        $table->primary(['article_id','tag_id']);
    });
}
```

I define tags relationship in my Article model like this:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

When I create Tags for any post I use following code:

```
// Managing tags
    $tags = collect(explode(',', request('tags')))->map(function ($tag) {
        return str_slug($tag, '');
    })->unique();

    // attach tag to article
    $tags->each(function ($tag) use ($article) {
        if (!Tag::where(['name'=>$tag])->exists()) {
            Tag::create(['name' => $tag]);
        }
        $tag = Tag::where('name', $tag)->get();
        $article->tags()->attach($tag);
    });
```

But problem is when I want to update tags for an article using follwing method I got an error:

```
// sync tag to article
$tags->each(function ($tag) use ($article) {
    if (!Tag::where(['name'=>$tag])->exists()) {
        Tag::create(['name' => $tag]);
    }
});
$article->tags()->sync($tags);
```

The error is:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'php' for column 'tag_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `article_tag` (`article_id`, `tag_id`) values (41, php))"
```

How can I resolve this Issue?

**Update**

I solved the issuse using following code:

```
   // sync tag to article
    $tags->each(function ($tag) use ($article) {
        if (!Tag::where(['name'=>$tag])->exists()) {
            Tag::create(['name' => $tag]);
        }
    });
    // this lines solve the problem
    $tags = Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)->get();

    $article->tags()->sync($tags);
```

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer to the question, so it's more visible to others and run into a similar issue.

Comment: I solved the issuse using whereIn method. The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.
 

       `// sync tag to article
        $tags->each(function ($tag) use ($article) {
            if (!Tag::where(['name'=>$tag])->exists()) {
                Tag::create(['name' => $tag]);
            }
        });
        // this lines solve the problem
        $tags = Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)->get();
    
        $article->tags()->sync($tags);`